# What's RESTful API, and does it mean anything for a front end developer?

Tags: rest, frontend

I've been reading around trying to understand what RESTful API is all about. I guess I understood the general outlines and a bit about how it's related to HTTP and all that.

In fact, one of the jobs I recently applied for required a 'must' knowledge of a RESTful API!! The job description was messy anyway and seemed it had been written by an HR person, or somebody who didn't actually have an advanced technical knowledge.

I fail to see how, as a frontend developer / UI/UX designer, I could benefit from the  vague RESTful API stuff? What's the connection?! Should really be bothered?

Thanks!

Comment: A _RESTful_ API that is done right is not vague, but many _RESTful_ APIs are done wrong and to not fulfill the design patterns you should with the HTTP protocol. If a RESTful API is done right then the one using it should know when to use `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE`, ..., how the urls and how the responses would look like, even if the API is used for the first time.

Comment: But that's a backend fuss in this case.

Comment: To create a correct _RESTful API_ yes. But if you create a UI that uses a RESTful API you need to know what kind of interactions will take place, and how you should design the UI and the UX so that that the user will be correctly notified. e.g.: you send a request to process some data, the server response with an accepted response, so you would need to request the status of the running job again and again until it is finished, ... . So you need to know that this can happen and how to request the current status.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and Precisely NO.

For only a front End Developer; it is not necessary, it is must (or SOAP bases API) for BackEnd Application Developer.
I am Android app Developer, made REST api for my app and my friend is just working on Web Page UI for that APP.!

Ajax calls are little to know for you.!

But one should know little bit about APIs, it never hurts :)

Comment: That's what I thought, and good to know. thank you. Frankly, I had a read trying to understand what the Rest is all about, and couldn't be more confused, and bored.

Comment: Kindly accept any one answer which satisfies u most.!

Answer (score 1):

RESTful api, and web services in general, are a way to abstract back ends from front end developpers. It allows front-end developpers to do their interfaces without the need to code any server-side logic.

Web services contain all the business logic. As a front-end developper, you'd need to know how to interact with such services, but the whereabouts of the api call are not required of you to understand.

Finally, it's a way to define clear separation between what the application looks like and what the application does.

Comment: Are you saying, I should be only bothered about sending and picking up/styling Ajax calls or data injection?

Comment: You need to know how to call web services, nothing else.

Comment: Yep, sounds good. Nothing new I need to do then :) Thank you!

Comment: Well you do need to know the http protocol very well.

Answer (score 1):

REST is a way to think applications. To make short, the client is stateless and you use HTTP methods for what they are designed to in order to interact with your server resources. You also leverage HTTP status codes, media types, content negotiation (Conneg).

If you want to know more about principles of RESTful services and Web API, you could have a look at this link: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

From client perspective the two main differences between REST and other e.g. SOAP webservices, that you have to use stateless communication (so you won't have a server side session, login, logout, etc...) and you have to use hyperlinks as request templates instead of building request from scratch. Because of these constraints your client breaks much harder by API changes.